# Homework Help - Python For Data Analytics (Linear Regression Modelling)

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis

**Part I:**
Perform linear regression modelling to predict the delay in days (between the Planned
and Actual date) in processing the claims, explaining the approach taken, including
any further data pre-processing needed for modelling.

**Part II:**
Discuss the results obtained from the modelling and state the linear regression
equation.

I'm trying to perform linear regression modelling to predict the delays.
But I'm not so sure which values should I be putting into my X and Y axis.
At first, I thought of using a `df['delay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Planned']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Actual'])` to plot one of the axis. But I am not sure what to do for the other axis, thought of using the count of delays but it wouldn't make sense.

Sorry in advanced. I'm quite new to this.

Code Snippet

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values=['Unkn', '???'])

# Count the number of missing values in each column
missing_counts = df.isna().sum()

# Print the number of missing values in each column
print('Missing value counts:\n', missing_counts)

# Drop rows with any missing value
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, how = "any")

# Print the updated number of rows and columns in the dataframe
# print('Updated dataframe shape:', df.shape)


model = LinearRegression()
model2 = LinearRegression()

planned = pd.to_datetime(df['Planned']).values.reshape(-1, 1)
actual = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual']).values.reshape(-1, 1)


df['Delay'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Actual']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Planned'])).dt.days


# Fit the model on the planned and actual data
model.fit(planned, actual)

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).reshape(-1, 1)
# model2.fit(df['Amount'],df['Delay'])

# Print the intercept and coefficients of the model
print("Intercept: ", model.intercept_)
print("Coefficient: ", model.coef_)

# print("Intercept: ", model2.intercept_)
# print("Coefficient: ", model2.coef_)
```

Sample csv to use

```
Claim_ID,Policy_No,Name,Planned,Actual,Created,Amount,Paid,Category,Terms,Region,Type2928509866,300764795,Roger Torres,17/1/2021,18/1/2021 0:00,20210112,3072.349,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928511094,300434439,Jason Jones,5/2/2021,16/1/2021 0:00,20210130,910.944,Yes,AT,EC05,LOC,L0012928516927,300769623,Robert Martin,18/1/2021,14/1/2021 0:00,20210113,567.936,Yes,AT,AB27,LOC,L0012928517338,300794332,Stacy Anderson,15/1/2021,18/1/2021 0:00,20210110,181.651,Yes,AT,AE14,LOC,L0012928518375,300792283,Mr. Adam Whitaker III,5/2/2021,8/2/2021 0:00,20210131,238.74,Yes,AT,EC05,LOC,L0012928518381,300782669,Robert James,18/1/2021,22/1/2021 0:00,20210113,772.492,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928521263,300739006,Amanda Garza,17/1/2021,23/1/2021 0:00,20210112,2854.26,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928528363,300729942,Courtney Robbins,17/1/2021,22/1/2021 0:00,20210112,2898.78,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928528375,300778870,Jonathan Peterson,19/1/2021,5/2/2021 0:00,20210115,5742.653,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928531494,300742521,Mrs. Donna Keller,4/2/2021,22/1/2021 0:00,20210130,371.7,Yes,AT,EC05,LOC,L0012928532226,300756072,Lisa Vincent,23/1/2021,29/1/2021 0:00,20210118,1457.347,Yes,AT,DE16,LOC,L0012928532560,300718130,Andre Gonzalez,3/2/2021,23/1/2021 0:00,20210129,758.015,Yes,AT,EC05,LOC,L0012928532814,300418007,Joan Elliott,19/1/2021,22/1/2021 0:00,20210114,183.71,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928532814,300418007,Joan Elliott,19/1/2021,22/1/2021 0:00,20210114,183.71,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928533426,300769623,Troy Phillips,14/1/2021,9/1/2021 0:00,20210109,4271.192,Yes,AT,AB27,LOC,L0012928533509,300418007,Megan Hendricks,19/1/2021,22/1/2021 0:00,20210114,293.001,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928533987,300726979,Denise Higgins,17/1/2021,22/1/2021 0:00,20210112,5558.286,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928534458,300718130,Kathleen Parker,23/1/2021,29/1/2021 0:00,20210118,194.206,Yes,AT,DE16,LOC,L0012928535047,300290370,Sean Brown,16/1/2021,26/2/2021 0:00,20210112,1648.274,Yes,AT,AD23,LOC,L0012928536356,300762301,Chelsea Ibarra,14/1/2021,15/1/2021 0:00,20210109,503.221,Yes,AT,CD89,LOC,L001
```

[main.py](https://pastebin.com/R2YWWxTL)
[Full CSV File](https://github.com/steadysteady/Linear-Regression-Modelling-for-Python/blob/main/test.csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not so sure if this is the answer you are looking for but this might be a good solution or a sample answer.

A few things missing from your code might be converting the date format for year month day. As well as changing the format to days.

Here's my attempt at your questions. Let me know if you need any more help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values=['Unkn', '???'])

# Count the number of missing values in each column
missing_counts = df.isna().sum()

# Drop rows with any missing value
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, how = "any")

# convert to datetime of Planned
df['Planned'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Planned'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# convert to yyyy-mm-dd format
df['Planned'] = df['Planned'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#convert datetime of Actual 
df['Actual'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

# convert to yyyy-mm-dd format
df['Actual'] = df['Actual'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')



model = LinearRegression()

planned = pd.to_datetime(df['Planned']).dt.day.values.reshape(-1, 1)
actual = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual']).dt.day.values.reshape(-1, 1)

# Fit the model on the planned and actual data
model.fit(planned, actual)

# Print the intercept and coefficients of the model
print("Intercept: ", model.intercept_)
print("Coefficient: ", model.coef_)
```